# $f(f^{-1}(V)) \neq V$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am looking for an example of metric spaces $X$ and $Y$, a continuous function $f: X \rightarrow Y$, and

- an open set $V \subset Y$ such that $f(f^{-1}(V)) \neq V$
- an open set $U \subset X$ such that $f^{-1}(f(U)) \neq U$

I was only able to find one that satisfies the second criteria which is $ X = \mathbb{R}, U = \mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}$ with $f(x)=x^{2}$. I can't find one that has both.

Comment: Also note: The set $U = \mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}$  is not an open set. Presumably you meant $U = \mathbb{R_{> 0}}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Let $f$ be a constant function.

Comment: I don't see how this one satisfies the first one.

Comment: Let $f:X\to Y$ be constant with $x\mapsto c$ for every $x\in X$. Now let $V\subseteq Y$ be open. Then $f^{-1}(V)\in\{\varnothing, X\}$ so that $f(f^{-1}(V))\in\{\varnothing,\{c\}\}$. So you only need $V\notin\{\varnothing,\{c\}\}$ to succeed. If $Y\neq\{c\}$ then you can do it with $V=Y$.

Comment: interesting results... thank you.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Your example only needs a minor tweak . . .

Let $X,Y = \mathbb{R}$.

Let $f:X \to Y$ be defined by $f(x) = x^2$, and let $U,V$ be given by 
$$U = (0,\infty),\;\;V=(-\infty,\infty)$$

Comment: I suspected that would be $V$ -- thank you.

Comment: You could also use $V=(-1,1)$, (which would be a proper open subset of $Y$).